# Extjs 4.2 Proxy Rest id parameter

Tags: rest, extjs, proxy

I am trying to access a REST service using *extjs* proxy rest, but the url that is being sent looks weird, take a look:

/rest/v1/distribution-list/1**?id=1**

I dont know why 'id' is being sent.
It shoul send `'/rest/v1/distribution-list/1'`
Any ideas?
this is my model

```
    Ext.define('Wave.model.DistributionList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'status', type: 'string'}

    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            read: 'GET', // defaults to GET
            update: 'POST',
            destroy: 'DELETE'
        },
        api: {
            read: '/rest/v1/distribution-list/',
            create: '/rest/v1/distribution-list/',
            update: '/rest/v1/distribution-list/',
            destroy: '/rest/v1/distribution-list/'
        }



    }

});
```

Cheers

-Henrique

Answer (score 0):

the ID have been send is setted by Extjs.you can change that using the idParam to changed to other one;

Answer (score 0):

Working with sencha-touch 2.3.1 and rest proxy, ExtJS creates the URL to the action methods with query string parameters, like you said: /rest/v1/distribution-list/?id=1.
If you don't want to append the id, you can change appendId to false inside proxy config.